# Java - Can't update JLabel's text

Tags: java, swing, debugging, constructor, jlabel

I have my Store class wherein i could add items to cart then it will increment the cart item number and the total amount.

I also have a view cart button like thing, if it is clicked it will show another frame where the items from the cart shows. When i click remove button from this cart frame i plan to decrement the count and total amount from the previous frame, but the setText method i used in the jLabel where the total price is located don't work.

I call this method from the cart frame then pass the price to be removed whenever i click the remove button

```
public void updateTotalAmount(double deduct){
    System.out.println("updateTotalAmount - "+deduct);
    tAPriceL.setText(String.valueOf(deduct)); //Total amount price label
    cICountL.setText(String.valueOf(--cICount)); //cart item count label
}
```

the system.out line is the only statement that works, the rest don't.

when i try to interchange the code like this.

```
public void updateTotalAmount(double deduct){
    tAPriceL.setText(String.valueOf(deduct)); //Total amount price label
    cICountL.setText(String.valueOf(--cICount)); //cart item count label
    System.out.println("updateTotalAmount - "+deduct);
}
```

the system.out now didn't work so i guess there is a problem on the setText part.

I can't figure out where is the problem. 
Could anyone help me with this?

here is the summary of this..
for the main store class.. example i have 5000 worth of items

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class NewClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JLabel tAPrice = new JLabel("5000");
    JButton viewcart = new JButton("view cart");

    public NewClass() {
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        add(tAPrice);
        add(viewcart);
        viewcart.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NewClass n = new NewClass();
        n.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        n.setSize(1150, 730);
        n.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void update(double deduct) {
        System.out.println("updated");
        tAPrice.setText(String.valueOf(Double.parseDouble(tAPrice.getText())
            - deduct));
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == viewcart) {
            Cart2 c = new Cart2();
            c.setVisible(true);
            c.setSize(250, 230);
        }
    }
}
```

and for the cart class... for example i wanna remove 1000 from the total amount

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Cart2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton remove = new JButton("remove");

    public Cart2() {
        add(remove);
        remove.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cart2 r = new Cart2();
        r.setVisible(true);
        r.setSize(250, 230);
        r.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == remove) {
            NewClass nc = new NewClass();
            nc.update(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, show other part of code where you add JLabel to JPanel. Did you try add final String to JLabel?  like: `tAPriceL.setText("blablalbla");`

Comment: @Katherine was some error thrown? if it stops working after set text possibly there might be an error thrown..

Comment: I mean it don't update.. the tAPriceL.setText(..)

Comment: @Fess
here's how i add the JLabel to the frame, the class extends the jframe .....
tAPriceL = new JLabel("0.0");
tAPriceL.setBounds(800, 65, 100, 20);
add(tAPriceL);

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) demonstrated issue with `JLabel#setText()` only, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: @AkhilKNambiar it didn't stop working, i could still add items then view them so i think there is no error

Comment: Are you updating the label from EDT? If not, the label might be updated but not repainted.

Comment: You may need to invalidate and repaint on the container

Comment: is it the label.repaint()? ... i'll make a SSCCE of this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `Cart2.actionPerformed()` you're allocating new `NewClass()` instead of using the calling instance of `NewClass`. Try passing instance of `NewClass` into `Cart2` constructor.

For example:

```
public class Cart2 extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    JButton remove = new JButton("remove");
    NewClass newClass;

    public Cart2(NewClass newClass) {
        this.newClass = newClass;
        add(remove);

        remove.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == remove) {
            // NewClass nc = new NewClass();
            newClass.update(1000);
        }
    }

}
```

Then in `NewClass`:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == viewcart) {
        Cart2 c = new Cart2(this);
        c.setVisible(true);
        c.setSize(250, 230);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Katherine did you copy the above example of `Cart2`?

Answer (score 3):

- don't use two or more `JFrames`, not on runtime, this is road to the troubles
- this is job for [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)
- put every `JComponents` to the `JPanel`, those `JPanels` put as `Cards`
- (maybe) then is place for only one `JButton` for whole GUI

Comment: I never knew there was a card layout before.. I wish had used this instead of what i use now.. Thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @Katherine I'm against complicating simple things, previously +1 for posting an SSCCE that make the sense for all readers here

Answer (score 2):

Though probably not the best, this may get people unstuck and is an early test in debugging:

```
tAPriceL.paintImmediately(tAPriceL.getVisibleRect());
cICountL.paintImmediately(cICountL.getVisibleRect());
```

**EDIT:** leaving this up, but isn't the fix in this case.

Comment: It still don't ... i poster the short code of what i am trying to do ... Can you check it if you don't mind.... 
Thanks alot .

Answer (score 2):

That's just because you are not updating the right NewClass instance...in the Cart2 actionPerformed, you create a new NewClass instance and update it.

You have to keep a reference to the NewClass frame instance in order to update it.

Comment: Yes, i missed that part.... now i know somehow know how to handle 2 or more related classes... Thanks :)